# Self sign certificate client authentication with client and server both on localhost

Tags: node.js, authentication, localhost, x509certificate, client-certificates

I have a node/express server running https on localhost:9002, and I want to use client certificate for a react app, running on localhost:8080 (webpack dev server).  The react app is using ajax request with superagent to the https server, and I have a passport middleware to check certificate automatically.

## Environment

Windows 10, Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98

## Setup

Using openssl, I created a root CA. Then I generated my server certificate, and a client certificate. This is the script used (I run it with git bash, so it's UNIX style but I'm on windows):

```
## CREATE CERTIFICATES FOR AUTHENTICATION

#########################################
## 1. Create Root Certificate Authority #
#########################################
# Root CA private key
openssl genrsa -out ./rootCA.key 4096
# Root CA certificate to register in RootCA store on OS
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ./rootCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out ./rootCA.pem

#################################
## 2. Create Server certificate #
#################################
# Create private key for server
openssl genrsa -out ./server.key 4096
# Create server certificate sign request (CSR) based on the private key
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out ./server.csr -key ./server.key -config ./server.csr.conf
# Create server certificate linked to the previoulsy created Root CA
openssl x509 -req -in ./server.csr -CA ./rootCA.pem -CAkey ./rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out ./server.crt -days 3650 -sha256 -extfile ./v3.ext

#################################
## 3. Create Client certificate #
#################################
# Create private key for client
openssl genrsa -out ./client.key 4096

# Create the Certificate Sign Request (CSR) file from the client private key
openssl req -new -config ./client.csr.conf -key ./client.key -out ./client.csr

# Self sign the certificate for 10 years
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in ./client.csr -CA ./server.crt -CAkey ./server.key -CAcreateserial -out ./client.crt

# Display the fingerprint of the newly generated fingerprint
openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -inform pem -in ./client.crt

# Generate a PFX file for integration in browser
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ./client.pfx -inkey ./client.key -in ./client.crt -passout pass:
```

Here are the different configurations used:

**server.csr.conf**

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
default_md         = sha512
prompt             = no
encrypt_key        = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
# distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = "FR"
localityName           = "Lille"
organizationName       = "Sopra Steria"
organizationalUnitName = "Webskillz"
commonName             = "localhost"
```

**v3.ext**

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
```

**client.csr.conf**

```
[ req ]
default_bits       = 4096
default_md         = sha512
default_keyfile    = server.key
prompt             = no
encrypt_key        = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
# distinguished_name
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName            = "FR"
localityName           = "Lille"
organizationName       = "Sopra Steria"
organizationalUnitName = "Webskillz"
commonName             = "localhost"
```

Finally, I addedd rootCA.pem to the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** using certmgr.msc, and I added the client.pfx and server.crt certificate to the **Personnal** store.

## Issue 1

Chrome is annoyingly redirecting http://localhost:8080 to https://localhost:8080, and I don't want to systematically open `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` to delete the localhost key...

## Issue 2

When I finally access to http://localhost:8080, I'm asked to choose the certificate I want to authenticate to https://localhost:9002 (yeay!), but I still get a 401, which is not caused by the passport cert-auth middleware (there is no log in my middleware).

## Additional information

### 1. Almost working setup

I managed to make this client/server setup work without a root certificate, but the issue was that I got a `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` from Chrome... That's why I added a root CA, following some advice on the World Wide Web... And indeed it corrected the problem, but then I was not able to authenticate, and Chrome began to redirect automatically http to https ಠ෴ಠ
Oh by the way, CORS is allowed server side so no problems from CORS.

### 2. Server code

Passport auth strategy: we just check for the fingerprint in the database.

**cert-auth.js**

```js
import { Strategy } from 'passport-client-cert';

export default new Strategy(async (clientCert, done) => {
  console.log(clientCert); // NO LOG HERE!!
  if (clientCert.fingerprint) {
    try {
      const user = await findByFingerprintInMyAwesomeDb({ fingerprint: clientCert.fingerprint });
      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      return done(new Error(err));
    }
  }

  return done(null, false);
});
```

**bootstrap-express.js**

```js
import passport from 'passport';
import certificateStrategy from 'cert-auth';

export default (app) => {
  // CORS setup, bodyparser stuff & all...
  // ... //

  // Using authentication based on certificate
  passport.use(certificateStrategy);
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.authenticate('client-cert', { session: false }));

  // Api routes.
  app.get('/api/stream',
    passport.authenticate('client-cert', { session: false }),
    (req, res) => {
      // Some router stuff
    });
};
```

**index.js**

```js
import https from 'https';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import bootstrapExpress from 'bootstrap-express';

const certDir = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'cert');
const listenPromise = server => port => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const listener = server.listen(port, err => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(listener)));
});

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.crt')),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

(async function main() {
  try {
    logger.info('Initializing server');

    const app = express();

    bootstrapExpress(app);

    const httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);
    const httpsListener = await listenPromise(httpsServer)(9002);

    logger.info(`HTTPS listening on port ${httpsListener.address().port} in ${app.get('env')} environment`);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}());
```

## Conclusion

Any help is welcome :)

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did many changes so that the chain of certificate could be clearer, but the reason I was still having 401 after all my efforts was because of this configuration in my express server:

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.crt')),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};
```

The working configuration is the following (replacing ca by the rootCA):

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'server.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.join(certDir, 'rootCA.pem')),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
};
```

This issue helped me by the way, but I only find it few minutes ago: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/253^

Additional Info: in order to avoid the redirection from http to https because my server was on the localhost DNS, I simply added a new DNS in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

`127.0.0.1  mysuperdns`

Therefore, the common name for the server certificate must be `mysuperdns`.